# Praying mantis egg sac started hatching then stopped

Tags: insects

My praying mantis egg sac started to hatch and then stopped. The bag did get dropped by my son on the floor. Killing the one that had just emerged & the other one that was trying to emerge. I’ve had no activity since then & I’ve tried moving it around my home to see if it was a temperature thing. It’s been a week since they started hatching. Is it done? Should I keep trying? Any insight or advice is appreciated.